# How to index my laravel collection by a property

Tags: laravel, sorting, indexing, collections

I have a laravel collection which I have sorted by the property 'name'.

```
{
"0":{"id":2,"name":"1","days":["2017-04-06","2017-04-07"]},
"1":{"id":3,"name":"2","days":["2017-04-08","2017-04-09"]},
"2":{"id":4,"name":"3","days":["2017-04-10","2017-04-11"]},
"6":{"id":10,"name":"4","days":["2017-04-12","2017-04-13"]},
"3":{"id":5,"name":"5","days":["2017-04-14","2017-04-15"]},
"4":{"id":6,"name":"6","days":["2017-04-16","2017-04-17"]},
"5":{"id":7,"name":"7","days":["2017-04-18","2017-04-19"]}
}
```

However the index of this collection has not changed. The indexes are now 0,1,2,6,3,4,5. Is it possible to re-index the collection in the order of the sorted collection?

So what I would like to have is:

```
{
"0":{"id":2,"name":"1","days":["2017-04-06","2017-04-07"]},
"1":{"id":3,"name":"2","days":["2017-04-08","2017-04-09"]},
"2":{"id":4,"name":"3","days":["2017-04-10","2017-04-11"]},
"3":{"id":10,"name":"4","days":["2017-04-12","2017-04-13"]},
"4":{"id":5,"name":"5","days":["2017-04-14","2017-04-15"]},
"5":{"id":6,"name":"6","days":["2017-04-16","2017-04-17"]},
"6":{"id":7,"name":"7","days":["2017-04-18","2017-04-19"]}
}
```

I tried using `$collection->values()`. But then I am left with:

```
[
{"id":2,"name":"1","days":["2017-04-06","2017-04-07"]},
{"id":3,"name":"2","days":["2017-04-08","2017-04-09"]},
{"id":4,"name":"3","days":["2017-04-10","2017-04-11"]},
{"id":10,"name":"4","days":["2017-04-12","2017-04-13"]},
{"id":5,"name":"5","days":["2017-04-14","2017-04-15"]},
{"id":6,"name":"6","days":["2017-04-16","2017-04-17"]},
{"id":7,"name":"7","days":["2017-04-18","2017-04-19"]}
]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [Laravel Collections docs says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-values) you can use **values()** on a collection for reseting the indexes:

```
$resetedIndexesCollection = $yourcollection->values();
```

> The values method returns a new collection with the keys reset to
>   consecutive integers.

In your case is not working because you don't have a collection, you have a json, at first you need to `json_decode` it to create an `array` and then collect the array, now you have a collection and you can apply the values() method for reseting the indexes, like this:

```
collect(json_decode('{
                "0":{"id":2,"name":"1","days":["2017-04-06","2017-04-07"]},
                "1":{"id":3,"name":"2","days":["2017-04-08","2017-04-09"]},
                "2":{"id":4,"name":"3","days":["2017-04-10","2017-04-11"]},
                "3":{"id":10,"name":"4","days":["2017-04-12","2017-04-13"]},
                "4":{"id":5,"name":"5","days":["2017-04-14","2017-04-15"]},
                "5":{"id":6,"name":"6","days":["2017-04-16","2017-04-17"]},
                "6":{"id":7,"name":"7","days":["2017-04-18","2017-04-19"]}
                }'))->values();
```

This is the result:

```
Collection {#287 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => {#288 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"name": "1"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    1 => {#407 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"name": "2"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    2 => {#408 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"name": "3"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    3 => {#409 ▼
      +"id": 10
      +"name": "4"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    4 => {#410 ▼
      +"id": 5
      +"name": "5"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    5 => {#411 ▼
      +"id": 6
      +"name": "6"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
    6 => {#412 ▼
      +"id": 7
      +"name": "7"
      +"days": array:2 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
collection = collect([5, 3, 1, 2, 4]);

$sorted = $collection->sort();

$sorted->values()->all();
```

Check the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sort